# Rate of Change Problem (is this a mistake?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking through an *OpenStax Algebra textbook*, mainly just reviewing concepts, and I discovered this problem below...

[image: rate of change problem]

Why is it not $282-10 / 6-0 = 45.33?$ Why are they putting in $292$?

Comment: You’re right, and they’re wrong. They’re mistakenly including the $10$ miles to her friend’s house in the total distance travelled, even though it was covered **before** the first $6$ hours started.

Comment: Thank goodness! This was just supposed to be a big refresher. Almost doubted for a minute that I knew how rates of change worked lol. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: It's badly written and poorly explained.  It should be explained as "In the 6 hours she traveled for a distance of $10$ to a distance of $282$ for a change in distance of $282 -10$" or "In 6 hours she had traveled $282$ miles but that includes the $10$ miles she traveled before she began measuring so her measure distance was $282-10$".  In either case, you are right and they made an error.  As to whether the error was a brain fart or a typo... I don't know.  Had they explained it better it'd be clear they error was on their end.